# Latest Driver for tjdbc not working - Talend

Tags: mysql, talend

Hi I'm using Talend Open Studio , version 6.5.1

I'm using tjdbc components. I changed the driver from **mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar** to **mysql-connector-java-5.1.45**

This change does not allow me to connect to mysql and returns the following error when I run the job.

May I know what changes must I do to get this working.

Starting job testutfbmb4 at 19:32 06/03/2018.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3975
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tJDBCConnection_1 (testutfbmb4)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2186)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
[statistics] disconnected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at cropin_talend.testutfbmb4_0_1.testutfbmb4.tJDBCConnection_1Process(testutfbmb4.java:515)
    at cropin_talend.testutfbmb4_0_1.testutfbmb4.runJobInTOS(testutfbmb4.java:1753)
    at cropin_talend.testutfbmb4_0_1.testutfbmb4.main(testutfbmb4.java:1524)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 17 more
Job testutfbmb4 ended at 19:32 06/03/2018. [exit code=1]
```

*

Comment: What is the version of java running on your computer?

Comment: Hi, the java version is java version "1.8.0_162"

Comment: Looks like an error in your connection string. Make sure it looks like this: jdbc:mysql://server:port/database?additionalParam=value

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue of not setting auto commit = false in the jdbc component. It worked now. Apologies for the confusion